# Holder Extension Operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, holder-spaces

As we all know, every holder continuous function is Bounded and uniform continuity in domain $\omega$. Now we give a more large domain $X$, then $\omega \subset \subset X$. Can we find a extension operator $E$ that makes $Eu|_\omega=u,$ $Eu$ is holder continuous function in the larger domain $X$?
If the general situation does not work, especially, $\omega$ is bounded?

Comment: You need some condition on $\omega$, if you use $$B(0,1) \setminus  \{ x: x_1>0, x_2 = 0,\dots , x_n = 0  \} $$ then you can't get a continuous extension to e.g. $B(0,2)$

Comment: @Calvin Khor  Thanks for your answer.If the domain $ω$ has good enough regularity(at least lipschitz boundary),can it be true?

Comment: i think yes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044581/can-we-always-extend-a-holder-boundary-continuous-function-to-whole-domain